# Magento Block Placement

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to add the block section below on the product detail section
currently its above

as shown in below image

[image: as shown into image]

does any one knows this?

my layout is

1st for facebook comment

```
<reference name="product.info">
<block type="facebookcomments/catalog_product_comments" name="product.info.facebookcomments" template="facebookcomments/catalog/product/comments.phtml"/>
```

2nd is for facebook like

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <block type="facebookilike/catalog_product_facebookilike" name="product.info.facebookilike" template="facebookilike/catalog/product/facebookilike.phtml"/>
```

still not getting this

Answer (score 1):

In `catalog_product_view` handle of your theme/module layout:

(**note** i'm pseudo-coding based on the debug block names in your screenshot. I may not have the correct block/template/handles, but you get the idea)

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="mageplace_facebook/like_catalog_product_facebooklike" 
           after="product.info" 
           name="facebook.like.block.name" 
           template="path/to/facebooklike/template.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Check the layout xml of the Facebook Comments module, as it's obviously in the right place.

Comment: rbaker86 can you please check? my layout files I edited the post with layout